# Is there a way to plot RK4 in LaTex?

Tags: plot

I have an end-of-semester project for Numerical Methods, and part of it is to plot the solution for RK4 in LaTeX. I've been researching for days and can not find any way to plot it. I would generally plot the line graphs by using {axis} but I have no idea what the formula for the lines are. I have calculated for RK4 in Matlab already is there any way to create the graphs in LaTeX?

[image: X_1 V X_2 V X_3 V X_4]

[image: X_1 V X_2]

[image: X_3 V X_4]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are scripts to export Matlab figures to Ti*k*Z (`matlab2tikz`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I fear, we cannot help you with the mathematical formula for the plot. But If you got this and also show how the result should look like, there might be a way to get it done.

Comment: Thank you for adding the desired output. What would the underlying formulae be that are needed to generate this?

Comment: You could export calculated by RK4 data from Matlab to csv file, then use, e.g., pgfplots to create the graphs.